# Android: remain multiple snakbar in a view

Tags: android, android-custom-view, android-toast

I have created custom snackbar according [this post](https://materialdoc.com/components/snackbars-and-toasts/#snack-bar) and i used this in the for loop:

```
public void onShowMsg(String msg) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 5 ; i++) {
        CustomSnackbar customSnackbar = CustomSnackbar.make(binding.linContainer, 10000);
        customSnackbar.setText(msg + i);
        customSnackbar.setAction("close", new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        });
        customSnackbar.show();
    }
}
```

I want in every loop a snakbar created and stay in the show state in view till i close that...

That's mean in my method i want to created 5 snakbar but just the last snakbar remain in view and all 4 snakbar gone.How can i do that dude?and it is possible?

> Edit

This is my full code:

```
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.design.widget.BaseTransientBottomBar;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public final class CustomSnackbar extends BaseTransientBottomBar<CustomSnackbar> {


    protected CustomSnackbar(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, @NonNull View content,
                             @NonNull android.support.design.snackbar.ContentViewCallback contentViewCallback) {
        super(parent, content, contentViewCallback);
    }

    public static CustomSnackbar make(ViewGroup parent, @Duration int duration) {
        // inflate custom layout
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        View content = inflater.inflate(R.layout.snackbar_view, parent, false);

        // create snackbar with custom view
        ContentViewCallback callback = new ContentViewCallback(content);
        CustomSnackbar customSnackbar = new CustomSnackbar(parent, content, callback);
// Remove black background padding on left and right
        customSnackbar.getView().setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);


        // set snackbar duration
        customSnackbar.setDuration(duration);
        return customSnackbar;
    }

    // set text in custom layout
    public CustomSnackbar setText(CharSequence text) {
        TextView textView = getView().findViewById(R.id.snackbar_text);
        textView.setText(text);
        return this;
    }

    // set action in custom layout
    public CustomSnackbar setAction(CharSequence text, final View.OnClickListener listener) {
        Button actionView = getView().findViewById(R.id.snackbar_action);
        actionView.setText(text);
        actionView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        actionView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                listener.onClick(view);
                // Now dismiss the Snackbar
                dismiss();
            }
        });
        return this;
    }

    public static class ContentViewCallback implements android.support.design.snackbar.ContentViewCallback {

        // view inflated from custom layout
        private View content;

        public ContentViewCallback(View content) {
            this.content = content;
        }

        @Override
        public void animateContentIn(int delay, int duration) {
            // add custom *in animations for your views
            // e.g. original snackbar uses alpha animation, from 0 to 1
            ViewCompat.setScaleY(content, 0f);
            ViewCompat.animate(content)
                    .scaleY(1f).setDuration(duration)
                    .setStartDelay(delay);
        }

        @Override
        public void animateContentOut(int delay, int duration) {
            // add custom *out animations for your views
            // e.g. original snackbar uses alpha animation, from 1 to 0
            ViewCompat.setScaleY(content, 1f);
            ViewCompat.animate(content)
                    .scaleY(0f)
                    .setDuration(duration)
                    .setStartDelay(delay);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You want them to be stacked on top of each other? Or do you want them to display right after the previous one was cancelled?

Comment: Yes, i want to e stacked on top of each other @pappbence96

Comment: Just a fast guess, try to use a different container for each snackbar.. Even tho, snackbars are not meant to be used this way..

Comment: Even if it can be done, the [Material Design Guidelines](https://material.io/design/components/snackbars.html#behavior) advise against displaying stacked snack bars.

Comment: in your case, you can use  `LENGTH_INDEFINITE` like `CustomSnackbar.make(rooView, CustomSnackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE)`. Then snackbar will not hide until you close it

Comment: When i am using `LENGTH_INDEFINITE` i got `Value must be ≥ 1 (was -2)` error. @PhanVanLinh

Comment: let me check, it funny, the document guide us to do like this :D https://materialdoc.com/components/snackbars-and-toasts/#snack-bar

Comment: please show your full `CustomSnackBar` class code to your question

Comment: I update my question @PhanVanLinh

Comment: also post the import

Comment: I have updated my post @PhanVanLinh

Comment: I copy your code and running and it working well. Can you take a picture when you receive error if you use `LENGTH_INDEFINITE`

Comment: Dude, i mean was warning with read line below the `LENGTH_INDEFINITE` command @PhanVanLinh

Answer (score 0):

Don't use for loop to display snackbar in that way seekbar will be close each time when new one come . Set click on each snack bar to show one by one. or use diff variables of your CustomSnackbar each time

Comment: In my loop i create new instance of `CustomSnackbar` each time by `CustomSnackbar.make()` @sagargujarati

Comment: Try using different variables every time and why you want to display 5 snackbars at same time ? maybe you can use custom dialog layout to get thing done or use bottom sheet dialog

Comment: Imagine i have a list of error that i want to show to user in `non blocking way` these errors  and i want to user close this error itself when read error @sagargujarati

Comment: Then i would suggest to use bottom sheet dialog with the list of your errors with cancel or ok button

Comment: Then there is no way to do that with snakbar?@sagargujarati